# why the es5 transpiled code for generator has a while(1)

Tags: generator, babeljs

As with babel repl, if we have es6 code like :

```
function* test() {

  let a = yield 1
  let b = yield 2
}
```

it will be transpiled into

```
"use strict";

var _marked =
  /*#__PURE__*/
  regeneratorRuntime.mark(test);

function test() {
  var a, b;
  return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function test$(_context) {
    while (1) {
      switch ((_context.prev = _context.next)) {
        case 0:
          _context.next = 2;
          return 1;

        case 2:
          a = _context.sent;
          _context.next = 5;
          return 2;

        case 5:
          b = _context.sent;

        case 6:
        case "end":
          return _context.stop();
      }
    }
  }, _marked);
}
```

Just cannot understand what is the purpose of the **while (1)** in the generated code for
(as in the case section, it uses **return** and it will just jump out of while(1) and also if while(1) is taking effects, the whole Javascript thread will be occupied and nothing else can be done)